# Probability question and logarithm

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Professor Gamble buys a lottery ticket, which requires that he pick six different integers from $1$ through $46$, inclusive. He chooses his numbers so that the sum of the base-ten logarithms of his six numbers is an integer. It so happens that the integers on the winning ticket have the same property— the sum of the base-ten logarithms is an integer. What is the probability that Professor Gamble holds the winning ticket?

ATTEMPT :
The product of the numbers have to be a power of $10$ in order to have an integer base ten logarithm. Thus all of the numbers must be in the form $2^m5^n$. Listing out such numbers from $1$ to $46$, we find $1,2,4,5,8,10,16,20,25,32,40$ are the only such numbers. Immediately it should be noticed that there are a larger number of powers of $2$ than of $5$. Since a number in the form of $10^k$ must have the same number of $2$s and $5$s in its factorization. But then How to proceed or there is any more elegant way ?

Comment: Am I right that he chooses integers with same probability?

Comment: Yes he is rational player @openspace

Comment: I guess then he should pick numbers, which product is the power of $10$.

Comment: Yes that is true @openspace

Comment: So the key is to determine how many ways you could factorize $10^m$ for $m \le 9$

Comment: Why m is less than 9 @openspace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112556/discussion-between-openspace-and-maths-student).

Comment: @mathsstudent $\log_{10}(20)$ is not an integer. So, suppose you pick: $1,2,4,5,8,20$, then $\log_{10}(1)+\log_{10}(2)+\cdots +\log_{10}(20)$ is not an integer.